# How to combine two vectors in a data frame

Tags: r

I am not able to combine two vectors like these

```
Height    Sex
178         M
167         M
183         M
...

Height    Sex
165         F
161         F
174         F
...
```

I would like to combine in a data frame like this

```
Height    Sex
178        M
161        M
174        M
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the logic here.  Can you explain it?

Comment: your example output doesn't demonstrate how you want to combine your data, however it seems you want to bind rows

Comment: try `rbind()`. could you please give more details?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dput()` on your vectors so that we understand more about the code behind them. Currently your data looks like it is contained within two data frames each with two columns (height and sex), as opposed to two vectors.

If the data is indeed within two data frames, you can combine them using `rbind()` as per Alice's suggestion.